# JFrame not loading all components unless created by main method inside class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcomponent, imageicon

I'm pulling my hair out trying to find out why the following doesn't work in certain cases:

```
public static void main(String[] str) {
    new Window(new DatabaseManager());
}
```

I run this exact code in two classes, with two different results.
When i run it from the `Window` class itself, it works perfectly.
When i run it from another class, it doesn't load all my window components.

Is this some memory related issue?
I tried to assign the Window object a variable name, but to no avail.
I am more than glad to explain further if need be.

`Window` is a JFrame, in case that matters. (It has many components inside, which are added by a weird algorithm taking much processing power (loading images).)

**EDIT**
Is there anyway i can give the EDT more time to process the requests?
**EDIT2**
Ok, so what i did was, i decided to do everything in the `Window` class (i made the main method there), as it works perfectly. I still have a lot to learn about Threads that I'm not cooked enough for. Everything is fine now : )

Comment: Are both classes in the same package?  It's not clear from your question if *anything at all* is loaded when you run from another class.

Comment: They are not in the same package, but Window is in a deeper `GUI` package.
Example: X.main, X.GUI.window

Comment: There is a "standard" `Window` class: `java.awt.Window`. Do you import `java.awt.*` in your code? [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html]

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) GUIs should be created & altered on the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.  This problem actually sounds like it is related to that.

Comment: I don't work with any thread except the one Java creates itself. I let swing take care of everything.

Comment: @PM77-1 +1 I actually renamed my actual class to Window, because my actual class is a little weird. Anyway i solved the problem (read edit2), thanks for helping.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for the guidance, i will do my best to have an example for my next question. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following inside your main method(event dispatching thread + setVisible)

```
Runnable doHelloWorld = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         Window w = new Window(new DatabaseManager());
         w.pack();
         w.setVisible(true);
     }
 };

 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doHelloWorld);
```

Comment: If the above fail confirm that you don't have basic imports issues or threading issues when adding other components/images(EDT -> event dispatching thread)

Comment: Above failed. And EDT?
I use ImageIcon(new URL(String url)) mostly to load images.
I also user Image.IO sometimes.

Comment: See this link for EDT http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

Comment: This is for a school related assignment, and we're not allowed to use threads or deal with them. We're to use swing. Is there anything simple that i can do to wait for the thread to finish loading? We're really just displaying our knowledge of reading and writing to a file and basic GUI. I took an extra mile and added pictures to my GUI. I tried to repaint() the GUI, but again, to no avail. Can i maybe do a Thread.sleep()? Please, anything would help T_T Sorry for being such a pest.

Comment: This wasn't the answer, but I want to thank the guy for trying to help me out. +1 :)